# Cannot read property 'DocumentDir' of undefined React-Native Firebase React-native-fetch-blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I have exhausted all threads on the internet and can't find a solution. 
I'm trying to photo upload to firebase from my react-native app using react-native-fetch-blob. 
RN ios simulator running iphone 6. 
Not using Expo
I have NOT tried running on android emulator yet, due to android env setup on different computer.

This line causes the error.

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'
```

I have read many of the tutorials about using react-native-fetch-blob.

I can't seem to link it correctly, or please tell me what my issue is.

```
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.49.3",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
```

What I've tried already...

```
npm install --save react-native-fetch-blob
react-native link
```

...

```
npm install --save react-native-fetch-blob
react-native link react-native-fetch-blob
```

...

```
rm -rf node_modules, then reinstall, then clean and build
```

...
I've followed the WIKI to manually link packages. Verified packages are linked via SS's
...

Clean and build after all of these scenario's.

I won't list EVERYTHING I've done because I've literally tried everything on stack and RNFB Issues/github.

Here are some screenshots from Xcode, RNFB is getting linked correctly, or at least I think.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have found this https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3

And will attempt a workout through AWS until someone can help with the linking of fetch blob. Ill update after I have time to work.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: Rebuild and reinstalling the app worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to install `react-native-fetch-blob` and get rid of the `Cannot read property 'DocumentDir of undefined'` by:

1. Following the [installation steps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob#user-content-installation) (I used npm to install the module).
2. **[Linking the package manually](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package)**

I think the important part that I was missing even previously is to run `pod install` for iOS.
For Android, the reason it didn't work for me previously might be related to the fact that I'm using `react-native-navigation` in my project, which means my `MainApplication.java` is different to the default one. Make sure you have the library listed and initialized in `getPackages()` method.

Here's my `MainApplication.java` for the reference:

```html
public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

  @Override
  protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
    ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
      @Override
      protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
      }
    };
    return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDebug() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }

  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    // Add additional packages you require here
    // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MapsPackage(),
      new RNFetchBlobPackage() 
    );
  }

  @Override
  public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return getPackages();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just kill all node process and start npm server and run application:

Step1: run command `killall -9 node`
    For windows users, run `taskkill /im node.exe`
    Run `taskkill /f /im node.exe` if the process still persists.

Step2: run command `npm start`

Step3: run command `react-native run-ios OR react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

I was cleaning up my project and removing packages I no longer needed.

I deleted FBSDK login from my project entirely and now no more errors.

"My code works. I don't know why my code works"

Answer (score 1):

For the folks out there in 2021:
You most likely are missing a dependency called `react-native-blob-util`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using expo? You'd have to remove expo and edit your app.json for your app to work again.

There's a workaround here: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/299

I haven't tried it myself though. I ended up removing expo altogether

Edit:

Can you try this in your MainApplication.java:

```
 import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;                                                                                 
 protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new RNFetchBlobPackage()                                                                                         
      );
    }
  };
```

Source: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package

Comment: Its already there. Everything is linked correctly, Ill upload a SS of this. Last picture in post.

Answer (score 0):

I got the access to app's local directory by

```
 RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardApplicationDir
```

You can append `RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardApplicationDir+"/files"`
to get into your app's document dir.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `rn-fetch-blob` version to  "0.10.15",then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not terminating the metro bundler of my project one and build the project two that's why my metro was accepting the configurations of project. So I terminated the project one's metro bundler and build project two it started its own metro bundler and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to terminate current process and rebuild your app after installing rn-fetch-blob then this error will be resolved

So, its better to restart vscode or the editor you are using after installing rn-fetch-blob package