# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DocumentDir') in rn-fetch-blob

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-fetch-blob, rn-fetch-blob

I have just installed this library but when I am importing it into my project I have an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DocumentDir')
```

windows - expo - android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'DocumentDir' of undefined React-Native Firebase React-native-fetch-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946494/cannot-read-property-documentdir-of-undefined-react-native-firebase-react-nati)